# windows subsystem for linux preserve file attributes in git repo

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, file-attributes

When sharing a git repo between wsl on windows10 and any linux, all files added/changed from wsl get the `rw-rw-rw` attributes, even if I explicitly do a `chmod ug+x file.py` before adding. If You do a `ls -l` in wsl all files are listed with rwxrwxrwx no matter what.

On linux I have to do a `find . -name "*.py" -exec chmod ug+x {} \;` on every pull/clone

What is the best way to fix this? Are there some settings in WSL? git hooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your git repo is somewhere in the windows file system, i.e. in `/mnt/c/path/to/git`. In this case WSL sets all permissions in order

> to best reflect the Windows permissions. ([FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#are-files-in-the-linux-drive-different-from-the-mounted-windows-drive))

There is currently no way in the stable build to change this behavior. But with 
the [insider build 17063](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-17063) the WSL team face this by implementing DrvFs support, which

> allows setting the owner and mode of files using chmod/chown, and also
>   the creation of special files such as fifos, unix sockets and device
>   files. ([Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-17063))